# How to sort a Javascript Object List by Date Colum

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I can't get this sorted by relevantDate.  I need newest date first. Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot in anticipation!

```
publications = [{
    "publicationDate" : "12.05.2022",
    "relevantDate" : "01.06.2022",
    "title" : "Bücher",
    "type" : "allgemein"
  }, {
    "publicationDate" : "04.05.2022",
    "relevantDate" : "21.05.2022",
    "title" : "Videos",
    "type" : "allgemein"
  }, {
    "publicationDate" : "14.04.2022",
    "relevantDate" : "25.05.2022",
    "title" : "Musik",
    "type" : "allgemein"
  }];


     publications.sort(function(a, b){
     return new Date(a.relevantDate) - new Date(b.relevantDate);
     });
```

Comment: You need to parse that date manually, just passing it to the `Date` constructor will not be reliable. There are plenty of examples of doing this on SO

Comment: I was in the process of supplying an answer this so that the requester could understand where their issue lay but the question was closed. 

I will briefly say that the format your dates are arriving in are not one that the Date object constructor understands. I would recommend if you have any control over the API to get the dates sent in a recognised ISO format. 

Failing that you can string manipulate them into something that the date constructor will accept.

Something like this might work, but I would check it works in all cases! 
`new Date("14.04.2022".split('.').reverse().join())`

Comment: Thank you very much, Glenn! This is great :-) It works:

`return new Date(a.relevantDate.split('.').reverse().join()).getTime() - new Date(b.relevantDate.split('.').reverse().join()).getTime();` or just

`return new Date(a.relevantDate.split('.').reverse().join()) - new Date(b.relevantDate.split('.').reverse().join());`